# How to enable X-Forwarded-Proto for aws Classic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, kubernetes

I have an nginx (nginx-ingress in k8s) setup behind AWS CLB, and according to [HTTP Headers and Classic Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html) and [Listener Configurations for Classic Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/using-elb-listenerconfig-quickref.html), I should be able to receive X-Forwarded-Proto header in nginx.

But after going through CLB listener configuration, I don't see anything about this setting, I set it up to forward TCP port 443 and try checking `$http_x_forwarded_proto` inside nginx, the `$http_x_forwarded_proto` returns null

Comment: It's my misunderstanding, Nginx create network loadbalancer for me, not classic load balancer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check you are getting other headers?

In Values.yaml, enable use-forwarded-headers

```
 config:
    use-forwarded-headers: "true"
```

Comment: I've added this and reload the ingress pod, It's still an empty string

Comment: `$http_x_forwarded_for` and `$http_x_forwarded_port` are also showing empty strings